# angular datepicker resets to 'DD-MMMM-yyyy' after date selection

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using angular date-picker as follows:

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" datepicker-popup="'dd-MMMM-yyyy'"
                   is-open="false" min-date="'2000-06-22'" max-date="'2015-06-22'" ng-model="logs.systemLog.dateStart"
                   date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close"/>
```

I set the default dates as follows:

```
 logs.systemLog.dateStart = '2014/8/19';
```

At the load, the date displays fine, but when I open the calendar and select a date, it resets to 'dd-MMMM-yyyy'. what's the issue here?

UPDATE:
I wanted to add another issue along the same line.

When I pass this date in to the REST service call, it gives me a bad request error. Following is how the URL looks like:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/AXServices/v1/logs/systemLogs/1408453832179/Tue%20Aug%2026%202014%2018:40:32%20GMT+0530%20(Sri%20Lanka%20Standard%20Time)/?page=1&pageSize=50
```

This is how I pass it to the service:

```
 function loadSystemLogs() {
    var service =  logServices.systemLogs();
    service.query({
        startDate : systemLog.dateStart,
        endDate: systemLog.dateEnd,
        page : 1,
        pageSize : 50
    },{}).$promise.then(function (response) {
        systemLog.logData = response;
    }, function (error) {
        if(error.status === 404){
            responseErrorFactory.redirectTo404();
        }
        else{
            messageNotificationFactory.setNotification("error",error.message);
        }
    });
}
```

I have already made the model properties date objects:

```
 systemLog.dateEnd = new Date();
 systemLog.dateStart = new Date().setDate(systemLog.dateEnd.getDate() - 7);
```

Appreciate if you can help.

Comment: So the calendar opens when you click on the text box? I mean you don't have any buttons that opens the calendar?

Comment: yes, it open when I click inside the calendar text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datepicker-popup should be like "dd-MMMM-yyyy" and not "'dd-MMMM-yyyy'". Try the following :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" datepicker-popup="dd-MMMM-yyyy"
                   is-open="false" min-date="'2000-06-22'" max-date="'2015-06-22'" ng-model="logs.systemLog.dateStart"
                   date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close"/>
```